# android activitygroup and listactivity

Tags: android, listactivity, activitygroup, extending-classes

I need to have a List in an Activity that is in a TabHost. The list gets opened when a button is clicked. I however want the new activity to open up and keep the tabs on top, so I created a class, TabActivityGroup, that extends the ActivityGroup and each of my activities extend TabActivityGroup. How would I create a list without extending ListActivity as I cannot extend two classes.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use ListActivity. Just use a regular activity. In the layout file do the following:

Give the list an id

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/name_of_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

Inside your activity use:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.name_of_list);

    mAdapter = new SomeSortOfAdapter(this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now you can make your activity be ActivityGroup 
:)

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I suspect you're going about this the wrong way.  Check out [the Tab Layout example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).  What you want to be able to do is add some subclass of the ListView as a subview of the TabHost view rather than having multiple inheritance.  I'd suggest reading through that tutorial and rethinking how you're structuring your app.